# Binary Search using a vector

Tags: c++, search, vector

So.. Ive already learnt of Binary Search and how it works and even tried it using a constant array without any input from the user , But now im trying to apply vector instead of array to have the user enter the values of both the list in which to search the numbers from **vector** and the target to search for. Here i used a normal divide&conquer while using an array

```
using namespace std;
int Binary_search(int x[],int size,int target){
    int maximum= size-1;
    int minimum = 0;
    int mean;
    while (maximum>minimum){
        mean = (maximum+minimum)/2;
        if (x[mean] == target){
            cout << "The number you're looking for is found! \n";
            return mean;
        }
        else if(x[mean] > target){
            maximum = (mean-1);
        }
        else{
            minimum = (mean+1);
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
int main(){
    int x[]={1,2,3,4,5};
    int a=sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]);
    int target=4;
    int show=Binary_search(x,a,target);
    if (show != -1){
        cout << "Your result is in the index: " << show;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My problem is that I made pretty much the same method using vector instead but it's showing either an infinite amount of **Your result is found at the index: ** (number of wrong index) . Or it doesnt show any result at all or even show that the result is not found , Differs each time somehow. Here's while using the vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int Binary_search(vector<int>x,int target){
    int maximum=(x.size())-1;
    int minimum = 0;
    int mean;
    while (maximum>minimum){
        mean = (maximum+minimum)/2;
        if (x[mean] == target){
            cout << "The number you're looking for is found! \n";
        }
        else if(x[mean] > target){
            maximum = (mean-1);
        }
        else{
            minimum = (mean+1);
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
int main(){
    unsigned int i;
    int n;
    vector<int>x;
    cout << "Enter the amount of numbers you want to evaluate: ";
    cin >> i;
    cout << "Enter your numbers to be evaluated: " << endl;
    while (x.size() < i && cin >> n){
        x.push_back(n);
    }
    int target;
    cout << "Enter the target you want to search for in the selected array \n";
    cin >> target;
    int show = Binary_search(x,target);
    if (show == -1){
        cout << "Your result is not found ! ";
    }
    else{
        cout << "Your result is in the index: " << show;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So I think the problem is in this part `int maximum=(x.size())-1;` , Maybe it's about how to use the size of vectors ? Could someone enlighten me up to this

Comment: Have you considered possibly that your array version was always broken, and using `vector` detected the breakage?  Second, why not hard-code the data into the vector and test, just like in the array version?

Comment: Do note that a binary search only works on a sorted data set.  If the user enters non sorted data then you need to sort the vector before you can run a binary search on it.

Comment: Good point noted , Thanks ! NathanOliver
I can't understand what do you mean exactly by *was always broken* could you explain @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: Sometimes using an array will hide off-by-one or other subtle bugs.  When a vector is used, there is a chance the program will behave differently, where the hidden bug is now exposed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `return mean` after this line

```
cout << "The number you're looking for is found! \n";
```

Just like you do in the array version.

Also, as mentioned in the comments, this will only work if the user enters in sorted data.

Answer (score 9):

Well, the other answers have helped to solve the issue, but in case you didn't know, there are built-in functions for performing **binary search** in `C++` that you can use them.

I will list the *functions* related binary search:

- [sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort): you can use binary search only on a *sorted* data, so you must guarantee that the data is sorted, before searching.
- [lower_bound](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound): this function returns an *iterator* to the first element that is **greater than or equal to** value.
- [upper_bound](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound): this function returns an *iterator* to the first element that is **greater than** value.
- [binary_search](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search):: this functions returns a *boolean*, whether the value is found or not (exactly as your program).

Here's a code sample that demonstrates the previous functions:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

typedef std::vector<int>::iterator iter;

int main() {

    std::vector<int> vec = {10, 20, 30, 30, 20, 10, 10, 20};

    // sort the data
    // the data will be:
    // 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 30, 30
    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());

    // index of the first element, greater than or equal to 20
    iter low = std::lower_bound(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 20);

    // index of the first element, greater than 20
    iter high = std::upper_bound(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 20);

    std::cout << "index of first element, greater than or equal to 20 is: " << (low - vec.begin()) << '\n';

    std::cout << "index of first element, greater than to 20 is: " << (high - vec.begin()) << '\n';

    // classic binary search
    // check whether a givin value exists in the array or not
    if (std::binary_search(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 99)) {
        std::cout << "Found\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Not found\n";
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks as well ! But that surely includes a predefined **algorithm** at the start doesnt it ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I didn't clearly understand your question.
**includes a predefined algorithm at the start**, if you mean that you should define the algorithm at the beginning and implement, then the answer is **NO**.
These are *built-in* functions, you can use them right away.

Answer (score 1):

problems:

1. no return. add

```
cout << "The number you're looking for is found! \n";
return mean;
```

2. goes too fast, it might skip some numbers

```
else if(x[mean] > target)
{
    maximum = mean;
}
else
{
    minimum = mean;
}
```

why goes too fast might be a problem?
try when

```
vector<int>x{1,2,3,4,5,6};
int target = 4;
```